# need to add text on overlay image in fabric js

Tags: image, html5-canvas, fabricjs

i have added overlay image in fabric js . But need to add text on this overlay 
image in canvas. it is made in fabric.js. how to do that?

Comment: I suspect you need to add a Text element on top.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to bring text layer on top of image layer. Like z- index in css.

You need to set sendtoBack for image. Then text layer will be in front.
**canvas.sendToBack(img);**